# How to hide @Deprecated marked APIs/Controllers when generating Swagger via Docket?

Tags: spring, documentation, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I am looking for a way to hide the APIs marked as @Deprecated so they are not visible on the swagger UI.
One way is to use the `hidden = true` in the @Operation annotation but thats too manual and not easy to toggle back if I decide that I want to view the Deprecated endpoints again.

Is there another way that we can achieve this via Docket config?

```
@Operation(
  tags = "Deprecated",
  deprecated = true
)
@GetMapping("/api/customer/order")
public String viewOrders() {
    //
}
```

```
@Bean
public Docket orderApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .groupName("order")
            .apiInfo(metadata())
            .select()
            .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/order/**"))
            .build();
}
```